# My custom GA4 events stopped sending after I added GTM to my website

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We have an SPA with a hardcoded GA4 tag. We have been successfully using the `window.gtag('event', eventName, {...})` method to send our custom events. We have hundreds of such custom events that are triggered by app logic baked into the code.

Recently we added GTM to add *other* 3rd party tags onto it. But we kept GA4 independent from GTM because we would have to reconfigure all those custom events on the GTM dashboard, and do a lot of work for something that already works.

**Problem is: our GA4 custom events stopped being collected on our GA4 dashboard since we added GTM alongside it**. They don't show on the GTM dashboard anywhere either. I have tried adding the GA4 tag onto GTM for good measure, and that didn't help either.

Question: how can I have GTM & GA4 coexist independently, and still have my existing GA4 custom events (`gtag('event', ...)`) be collected?

Note: If advised, I am willing to remove the hardcoded GA4 tag from my code and migrate it onto GTM, if there is a way for me to keep using my `gtag` events without having to do a ton of work on the GTM UI.

Sorry if I suck at asking this question. I'm still a newbie in GA.

Comment: GTM also uses gtag, and any config for a measurement id in GTM may override what you have directly set in gtag. Is GTM configuring the same measurement id in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

As Tony indicated, you really don't want to mix gtag calls sources on the same pages. Either go with GTM or gtag.js. And the best practice is to go with GTM to keep all your analytics logic in one place, so really the proper solution is exactly what you're avoiding. Your gtag() implementation is just a tech debt at this point, really.

If you want to keep your analytics in two places then what you want to do is first make sure GTM has no ga4 tags active, then go and debug your gtag calls in the console/network tab to see what's happening. As well as the loading of your gtag.js library.

If these steps won't make the issue apparent, then add screenshots and description of your debugging.